# Accessing array index with Rivets.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, templating, rivets.js

I am wondering why accessing an index of an array bound in rivets.js works with the . operator and not the standard access way with [].

For example

let's say we bind

```
var binding = {name: "binding", arr: [0,1,2]}
rivets.bind(document, {binding: binding});
```

then in our html if we do, it won't work

```
<span> {binding.arr[0]}</span>
```

but if we do

```
 <span> {binding.arr.0}</span>
```

The 0th element of the array is successfully accessed.

Where in rivets is this behavior documented? Is this the standard way to access array elements in templating engines? I wasn't able to find it anywhere and it's really bothering me.

Comment: Rivets does not run Javascript code in the HTML through exec. Parsing proper array syntax requires that that syntax is compiled with the exec function. For example if you have `{ binding.arr[i - 1] }`, this can not be computed without `exec`.
This can be seen as a limitation, but it comes very handy when building an application in a sandbox that does not allow `exec`, for example a Google Chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span> {binding.arr.0}</span>` works because Arrays are objects. So it works the same way other objects do with the `.` operator (returns `obj[key]`).

Ideally while working with arrays you should be using `rv-each`.

for some reason if you have to access item at specific index and is unconfortable about `<span> {binding.arr.0}</span>` looks confusing or unreadable, I suggest creating a formatter along the lines of:

```
rivets.formatters.itemat = function(value,index){
  if(!(value && value instanceof Array))
    return null; // throw some error if required
  return value[index || 0];
}
```

which can be used like

```
<span> {binding.arr | itemat 0}</span>
```